# Send audio recorded with Media Recorder to server via php

Tags: php, audio, mediarecorder, mediarecorder-api

I recently started to study the Media Recorder API and so far I managed to record audio in the browser using this API, play that audio in the browser and download it do my disk. Now, I want to send the recorded audio to a PHP server. How can I do that?

Here's my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    <button id="record" disabled> record </button>
</p>
<p>
    <button id="stop" disabled> stop </button>

<p>
    <audio id="audio" controls></audio>
</p>
<p>
    <a id="downloadLink" href></a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var recordButton, stopButton, recorder;
    var chunks = [];
    var downloadLink = document.querySelector('a#downloadLink');
    window.onload = function() {

        recordButton = document.getElementById("record");
        stopButton = document.getElementById("stop");



        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                audio: true
            })
            .then(function(stream) {

                recordButton.disabled = false; 
                recordButton.addEventListener('click', startRecording);
                stopButton.addEventListener('click', stopRecording);
                recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream );
                recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', onRecordingReady);
            });
    };

    function startRecording() {
        chunks = [];
        recordButton.disabled = true;
        stopButton.disabled = false;
        recorder.start();

    }

    function stopRecording() {
        recordButton.disabled = false;
        stopButton.disabled = true;
        recorder.stop();
    }


    function onRecordingReady(e) { 
        chunks.push(e.data)
        var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
        audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.data);
        var audioURL = audio.src;
        downloadLink.href = audioURL;
        downloadLink.innerHTML = audioURL;
        var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000));
        var name = "audio_" + rand + ".wav";

        downloadLink.setAttribute("download", name);
        downloadLink.setAttribute("name", name);
        audio.play();

    }
    </script>
```